# The currently selected variant "arm-debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 4 split apks are compatible with the current device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, telegram

I have imported the project from https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram. I have generated the signed APK and when I try to run in the emulator it shows the following error.

```
05/15 17:14:42: Launching TMessagesProj
The currently selected variant "arm-debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 4 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "480" and ABIs "x86".
Error while Installing APK
```

How can I fix this error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Really weird. It happened to me out of nowhere. I was testing same project on same device and suddenly got this error. Solved by following @尹振东 answer. Restarted the Android Studio and reconnect the device.

Answer (score 10):

In the [TMessagesProj/build.gradle](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle) file, right in the `defaultConfig` section add

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "x86"
    }
```

So the  `defaultConfig` section is:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionName "3.10.1"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "x86"
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: it's conflicted for me, cuz my splits abu filters are set: armeabi-v7a, and I must use this filter, what can I do?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to restart the android studio, and then reconnect the device

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Genymotion uses x86 instead of arm architecture, and doesn't seem to come with libhoudini (arm to x86 translator) pre-installed.

You have two options:

```
install the native arm translation, which I have never had much luck with, will occasionally crash my devices with no warning, and is the #1 cause of crashes in my app in production - http://mir.cr/0ZIO8PME
```

OR

```
Build a native x86 binary of your app. Assuming you are using the most recent Cordova 4.0, this is default with gradle, and you will be able to find an x86 build already done along side the arm build. According to the Cordova release notes, you can manually trigger gradle if it isn't already enabled with:

cordova build android -- --gradle
```

Best of luck!